# Python plugin development. how implement merge functionality in a window

Tags: pyqgis, merge, pyqt

I want to create a plugin and in a window I need to make the same functionality as the toolbar advance digitize (merge, split features ...).

Is there any possibility of calling the functions already implemented in QGIS (merge, split features ...) without having to create them from scratch?

If so, I seek documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use virtual QAction from QgsInterface Class. There is for your purpose,
**actionSplitFeature()** that you can trigger when the user click on your button.

for example you can define a function like that (you can add the code you need for your task, like set the layer to work with, selecting features,...):

```
def mySplitFeature():
    self.iface.actionSplitFeatures().trigger()
```

and connect your button to this function like that:

```
self.dockwidget.your_button.clicked.connect(self.mySplitFeature)
```

so when you click your button, the split features tool will be trigger.

Have a look to the QgsInterface class documentation to see all Qaction available : https://qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html

Answer (score 1):

You use `processing.runalg()` (remember to `import processing` first) to call existing algorithms.

More detail and help in identifying the correct syntax for algorithms can be found in the [QGIS documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.htm).